# How can we give the check on shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Any one can help me do this with shell script:

1. When VM startups, it checks if a folder (`dbsync-installdir`) exists
2. if it does not exists, it will download the ZIP file using `wget`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

To check check if a directory doesn't exist:

```
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Here if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
    wget http://url_to_zip_file
fi
```

To extract zip files see `man unzip`

Also you can check if a directory exists:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Here if $DIRECTORY exists.
fi
```